# Configuring rsync over SSL

Tags: nginx, ssl, rsync

I want to configure rsync to accept SSL/TLS connections from port 874 on my server. I've followed the steps in rsyncd.conf(5) man page, configured a domain and got an SSL certificate for it. However, it yields me this error when I try to connect using rsync-ssl:

```
verify depth is 4

---MOTD MESSAGE HERE---

@ERROR: protocol startup error
rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1833) [Receiver=3.2.4]
```

My nginx.conf stream section:

```
stream {
    server {
        listen 874 ssl;
        listen [::]:874 ssl;
        ssl_certificate /{...}/fullchain.cer;
        ssl_certificate_key /{...}/private.key;
        ssl_session_timeout 1440m;
        ssl_session_tickets off;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384";
        ssl_dhparam /{...}/ssl-dhparams.pem;
        proxy_pass localhost:873;
        proxy_protocol on; # Requires "proxy protocol = true"
        proxy_timeout 1m;
        proxy_connect_timeout 5s;
    }
}
```

And my rsyncd.conf:

```
uid = nobody
gid = nobody
use chroot = no
max connections = 20
syslog facility = local5
pid file = /run/rsyncd.pid
lock file = /run/rsync.lock
log file = /var/log/rsync.log
motd file = /etc/rsyncd.motd

--- Directory sections here---
```

What I'm doing wrong?

**Update**: I'm using Arch Linux as a server. The client-side works perfectly (but not the server-side/daemon).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you please check(share) any related logs...? The answer must be there. Plus sometimes this could be related to SELinux, if you have your SELinux enabled check your logs with anything SELinux related. However if this is true please do not disable SELinux but troubleshoot it.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't have any related log in my /var/log folder.

Comment: Also, I don't use SELinux

Comment: I think there is a [ready to use](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync-ssl.1.html) solution available from the vendor if i read correctly

Comment: Yes, but client-side works perfectly. I want to fix the server side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of digging, I eventually found the solution in [this site](http://www.netbits.us/docs/stunnel_rsync.html). It is outdated and I needed to change some things, so I'm going to explain how to do it:

Fist of all, my server uses Arch, so there are things that may vary when you follow these steps.

1. Install rsync, openssl and stunnel.
2. Configure rsyncd (obviously), which I'm not going to explain here.
3. Edit `/etc/stunnel/stunnel.conf` and uncomment (or create) the following line: `include = /etc/stunnel/conf.d`. This is not required, but it will simplify a lot everything else.
4. Create the folder `/etc/stunnel/conf.d` and create a file there. I will name it `rsync-ssl.conf`.
5. Edit that file and write the following code (edit the sections between brackets):

   ```
   cert = [PATH_TO_YOUR_CERTIFICATE]
   key = [PATH_TO_YOUR_PRIVATE_KEY]

   client = no
   pid = /var/run/stunnel.pid

   [rsync]
   accept = 874
   connect = 873
   ```

   Remember that you'll need a valid SSL certificate for your domain. I recommend using Certbot/acme.sh with Let's Encrypt.
6. Run `systemctl disable --now stunnel rsyncd` and `systemctl enable --now stunnel rsyncd`. In some cases, you may need to restart the whole server.
7. Done! Now you should be able to use rsync-ssl to connect to the server. Remember that you need to a domain name that is contained within the certificate that you have specified in the `rsync-ssl.conf` file. Else it will fail.